# Dojo 1.9: Is it good practice to mark attach points as private in a template?

Tags: javascript, dojo

When [writing your own widget](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/writingWidgets.html), is it good practice to mark a `data-dojo-attach-point` as private using underscore within template HTML?

e.g.

```
<div>
    <div id="app_header" data-dojo-attach-point="_header" data-dojo-type="app/header/view/Header"></div>
    <div id="app_content" data-dojo-attach-point="_content" data-dojo-type="app/content/view/Content"></div>
    <div id="app_footer" data-dojo-attach-point="_footer" data-dojo-type="app/footer/view/Footer"></div>
</div>
```

So the above example template shows 3 divs with attach points named using an underscore, marking them as private: `_header`, `_content` and `_footer`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing overwhelmingly good or bad about this convention. Remember that putting an underscore in front of a variable name doesn't inherently make it private - it's typically used to indicate that this variable *should be treated as though it were a private variable.*

Since you're making your own widget, you may find the need for both; if you want to express that the node the `dojo-attach-point` points to should only be accessible within the widget, perhaps an underscore prefix would be helpful. However, it isn't unimaginable that you may find the need to pass these pointers around to other widgets. It really depends on the implementation of your project

As I see it, here's a summary:

1. "Private" `dojo-attach-points` should be used to indicate that this node should not be referenced outside the widget declaration.
2. "Non-private" `dojo-attach-points` can be passed to other widgets.

Comment: FWIW, I can't recall ever seeing dijit's own widgets prefix attach points with underscores, but I could see going either way on this as well.